# "Asp.Net Development Server Runs" não fecha ao fim da execução

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

Mesmo ao final da execução da aplicação o **Asp.Net Development Server Runs** permanece aberto no *systray*.

[image: SS]

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2010.

1 - Isto é um comportamento normal?

2 - Pode gerar algum problema?

3 - Teria como contornar a situação?